# Obtain value from href with name using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to pass values to jquery if an a href has a name? I have posted my code which I think illustartes the point. In php, I would use a switch statement, but I am novice to jQuery, so could use some help. For example, if a user clicks on the link with the name of billing, I need to capture that value and process in jquery. Thanks

html

```
<ul class="greybox">
        <li><a class="anchorTest" name="billing" href="#">Billing</a></li>
        <li><a class="anchorTest" name="rpterror"href="#">Report Error</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: You should think about doing it in pure `JavaScript` to improve your [**website's/app's performance**](http://jsperf.com/select-name-attribute-of-children-jquery-vs-purejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.greybox a').on('click',function(){
   if(this.name === 'billing'){
      // billing clicked
   }
});
```

Comment: Tried with alert, but nothing fires.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.greybox a').click(function (e) {

    // Cancel the default action (navigation) of the click.
    e.preventDefault();

    switch (this.name) {
        case "billing":
            alert("Billing!");
            // Your code for Billing here
            break;
        case "rpterror":
            alert("Report Error!");
            // Your code for Report Error here
            break;
        default:
            alert("Default statement!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.greybox a').click(function(){
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attr to get the name of the link you have clicked.

e.g.

```
$('.greybox a').click(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name selector

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```
$('a[name="rpterror"]');
```

I HIGHLY recommend looking through all the selectors available to you

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

You never know when you need to use something you didn't know existed.